# exponential function and inequality

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

I have a hard time solving this one.
I'm sure there is trick that should be used but if so, I can't spot it.

$$(3\cdot4^{-x+2}-48)\cdot(2^x-16)\leqslant0$$

Here is what I get but I'm anything but confident about this:

$$3\cdot(2^{-2x+4}-16)\cdot(2^x-16)\leqslant0$$
$$(2^{-2x+4}-2^4)\cdot(2^x-2^4)\leqslant0$$
$$2^{-x+4}-2^{x+4}-2^{-2x+8}+2^8\leqslant0$$
$$2^{-x+4}+2^8\leqslant2^{x+4}+2^{-2x+8}$$

So far, I'm already not 100% sure but then, I'm not sure at all:

$$(-x+4)\cdot \ln(2)+8\cdot \ln(2)\leqslant(x+4)\cdot \ln(2)+(-2x+8)\cdot \ln(2)$$

This is nonsense, can someone correct me please?
Thanks.

Comment: Your big error is that $\ln(a+b)\ne\ln a+\ln b$

Comment: I think the trick is that a product is non-positive if at least one of the terms is zero, or if the terms are opposite in sign

Comment: I’d use that fact on:  $$(2^{-2x+4}-16)\cdot(2^x-16)\leqslant0$$

Comment: @Andrei: Can you spot when I did that error? I'm not seeing myself making it. Thank you

Comment: @BachirMessaouri Right after the "So far ..." sentence. How did you get that from the line above?

Comment: It's your third last equation. But forget about that for a moment. You want to know when a product of two terms is negative (non positive). This happens when the terms have opposite signs.

Comment: @lcv and Joe: I get what you say. The inequality is true if one of the term is equal to zero or the two terms are opposite. But how does it translate in maths? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expound on the previous problem (I can't comment), the interval should be

$$(-\infty,0]\cup[4,\infty)$$

For if

$$(1-t)(t-16)\le0$$

then

$$(t-1)(t-16)\ge0$$

So

$$(2^x-1)(2^x-16)\ge 0$$

Note that if $x=2$, we have

$$(4-1)(4-16)=-36$$

so $2$ can not be a solution

Comment: This is also true in the original problem since $$(3\cdot 4^0-48)(4-16)=(-45)(-12)>0$$

Comment: I'm reading you carefully. as soon as I get it I get back to you very quickly. Thanks!

Comment: We agree that your solution is the opposite of the one hamam_Abdallah suggested right ? And when I do a sign table I get what you get: anything between 0 and 4, (both excluded) doesn't fit the inequality, everything else does.

Comment: I appreciate the upvotes and the green check, but I don't think mine should be the answer, since @hamam_Abdallah corrected his solution and it's a more complete solution.  I wasn't allowed to comment so I had to write my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

If we put $t=2^x>0$, the inequation becomes

$$48(\frac{1}{t^2}-1)(t-16)\le 0$$

which equivalent to
$$(1-t)(1+t)(t-16)\le 0$$

or
$$(1-t)(t-16)\le 0$$

thus
$$2^x\le 1 \; or \;2^x \ge2^4$$
so, the answer is
$$x\le 0 \;\; or \;\; x \ge 4$$

Comment: Thank you very much .I have to wrap my head around this one as I don't get it yet. When I do, I'll come back and accept the answer.

Comment: @BachirMessaouri, to think about it, start with thinking about when $2^x -16$ is positive/negative. Then think about when $2^{-2x+4} -16$ is positive/negative.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah: one question please: why (1-t).(1+t) instead of ((1/t)-1).((1/t)+1)? Everything else is understood. Thank you.

Comment: @Joe; I got this part now, thanks to you.

Comment: @BachirMessaouri because the denominator $t^2$ is positive.

Comment: Great! You’re welcome.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it as I got everything you told me guys (thank you all). Still, @hamam_Abdallah: if your logic is very sound, it seems the actual answer is about the opposite of yours as anything between 0 and 4 does NOT fit the inequality and everything else does.
So the answer is not 0≤≤4 but rather  (−∞,0]∪[4,∞) , right ?
Mando's answer seem to make sense and I eventually used a sign table which gets me the same answer than him. You agree?

Comment: @BachirMessaouri Oh yes of course. the coefficient of $t^2$ is negative.